# Feign Client throws HystrixTimeoutException even though the underlying request is successful

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, hystrix, feign

I have a feign client like this with endpoints to two APIs from PROJECT-SERVICE

```
@FeignClient(name = "PROJECT-SERVICE", fallbackFactory = ProjectServiceFallbackFactory.class)
public interface ProjectServiceClient {
    
    @GetMapping("/api/projects/{projectKey}")
    public ResponseEntity<Project> getProjectDetails(@PathVariable("projectKey") String projectKey);

    @PostMapping("/api/projects")
    public ResponseEntity<Project> createProject(@RequestBody Project project);
}
```

I'm using those clients like this:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  
    @Autowired
    private ProjectServiceClient projectServiceClient;


    public void doSomething() {
         // Some code
         ResponseEntity<Project> projectResponse = projectServiceClient.getProjectDetails(projectKey);
         // Some more code
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
         // Some code
         ResponseEntity<Project> projectResponse = projectServiceClient.createProject(Project projectToBeCreated);
         // Some more code
    }
}
```

My problem is,  most of the times (around 60% of the time), either one of these Feign calls result in a `HystrixTimeoutException`.

I initially thought there could be a problem in the downstream micro service (PROJECT-SERVICE in this case), but that is not the case. In fact, when `getProjectDetails()` or `createProject()` is called, the PROJECT-SERVICE actually does the job and returns a `ResponseEntity<Project>` with status `200` and `201` respectively, but my fallback is activated with the `HystrixTimeoutException`.

I'm trying in vain to find what might be causing this issue.

I, however, have this in my main application configuration:

```
feign.hystrix.enabled=true
feign.client.config.default.connect-timeout=5000
feign.client.config.default.read-timeout=60000
```

Can anyone point me towards a solution?

Thanks,
Sriram Sridharan

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix's timeout is not tied to that of Feign. There is a default 1 second execution timeout enabled for Hystrix. You need to configure this timeout to be slightly longer than Feign's, to avoid `HystrixTimeoutException` getting thrown earlier than desired timeout. Like so:

```
feign.client.config.default.connect-timeout=5000
feign.client.config.default.read-timeout=5000
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=6000
```

Doing so would allow `FeignException`, caused by timeout after 5 seconds, to be thrown first, and then wrapped in a `HystrixTimeoutException`